# Writing a serialized object to file garbaged?

Tags: java, file

```
try
        {
            File dataFile = new File("C:/Users/keatit/Desktop/players.txt");
            if(!dataFile.exists())
            {
                dataFile.createNewFile();
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/keatit/Desktop/players.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(players);
            oos.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex)
        {
            System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException ioex)
        {
            System.out.println(ioex.getMessage());
        }
```

I have a class player which implement Serializable but when I write objects to files the text is messed up and looks like the following. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

"¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w   sr players.playerÌ`~%×êòœ I ageL  firstNamet Ljava/lang/String;xp   t Trevorsq ~    t Michaelax"

Comment: Oh forgot to add the "players" is an ArrayList of type<player>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *binary* serialization. It's not meant to be writing to a human-readable text file. For that, you should look into something like JSON or YAML. I'd strongly recommend *against* writing to a `.txt` file using `ObjectOutputStream` - it gives the wrong impression.

The point of binary serialization is to be able to deserialize it later with the same serialization protocol - so in this case you'd use `ObjectInputStream`. You should find that that is able to correctly deserialize the object stored in your file.

(Side-note: `FileOutputStream` will create a new file automatically if it doesn't exist - you don't need to do so yourself. Additionally, you should use a try-with-resources statement to clean up automatically, rather than just calling `close()` outside a `finally` block.)